# Comparing gradients for 3 slopes on different scales

Tags: r, regression, linear, normalization

I am trying to compare slopes/gradients for three Groups (A, B, and C): the values for each Group are on essentially the  same scale for the independent variable (Age), but are on markedly different scales for the dependent variable (Performance). Specifically, I am trying to ascertain which of the three trendline pairs (i.e., A v B; A v C; B v C) is most similar, despite them all being on separate scales (if this is even possible, or mathematically meaningful).

I am aware of z-score normalisation, and am wondering whether it might be applicable here? Since I am a bit hazy on the mathematics, I am not sure if normalising Performance is acceptable, or whether it might change the shape of the slopes/lines in a meaningful way (e.g., by attenuating an accelerated decline in performance at higher ages, or similar).

If anybody has any thoughts about how best to skin this cat, I would very much appreciate hearing from you. Thank you.

This is what I have so far (reprex)

```
# Create data frame
df<-
  data.frame(
    Group=c(
      "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
      "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
      "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"
    ),
    Age=c(
      68,50,65,60,64,70,59,58,57,43,
      55,66,61,53,60,61,58,61,65,65,
      63,49,65,58,50,60,60,63,49,59
    ),
    Performance=c(
      2,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,
      30,20,40,20,20,40,20,20,30,20,
      8,12,8,8,16,8,8,16,8,8
    )
  )

# Normalise data (each subset separately)
## A
A<-
  subset(
    df,
    Group=="A"
  )

A$Performance_norm<-
  scale(
A$Performance,
    center=T,
    scale=T
  )

## B
B<-
  subset(
    df,
    Group=="B"
  )

B$Performance_norm<-
  scale(
B$Performance,
    center=T,
    scale=T
  )

## C
C<-
  subset(
    df,
    Group=="C"
  )

C$Performance_norm<-
  scale(
C$Performance,
    center=T,
    scale=T
  )

df<-
  rbind(
    A,
    B,
    C
  )


# Create linear models
## Raw data
lm<-
  lm(
    Performance~
      poly(Age,2)+
      Group+
      poly(Age,2)*Group,
    data=df
  )
summary(lm)

## Normalised data
lm_norm<-
  lm(
    Performance_norm~
      poly(Age,2)+
      Group+
      poly(Age,2)*Group,
    data=df
  )
summary(lm_norm)

# Remove temporary files
rm(A,
   B,
   C,
   df,
   lm,
   lm_norm)
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by the "gradient" for a group.

Comment: Hi whuber, thanks for your response. I will try to clarify my question. By gradient I mean "slope" of the relationship between the two variables for a given group (e.g., "A"). I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: More generally, I am interested to know which pairwise combination of slopes is most similar. I am not sure if this can be compared directly if the measurements of the dependent variable are on different scales. Specifically, imagine that A and B are two groups of women under different treatment regimes, and group C is a group of men. The performance of the men is expected to be much higher than that of the women. I am not interested in absolute performance per se but the degree to which age attenuates it.

Comment: I am concerned that the generally higher performance of men might hinder direct comparison of the slopes (although, as I said, I am not sure that it would). I was thus considering z-score normalising each dataset separately, and comparing the normalised slopes, but am unsure of whether this might actually distort the shape of the slopes

Comment: In terms of comparing slopes, I mean, for instance, the fact that you can add a Factoral Level*Independent Variable term to a `lm()` (e.g., Sex*Age) object and examine the p-value, with a p < 0.05 being taken as evidence that the slopes for Men and Women are non-parallel. I wish to examine "how" parallel/non-parallel these slope pairs are, if this is even possible. Thanks